# Javascript variable missing characters

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am setting a javascript variable from ASP.net `<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>`

```
var username = '<%=HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name%>';
```

outputs "domain sername"

Basically it takes out the backslash and first letter of the username.  Why is it removing those two characters?

Comment: This has more to do with ASP.net than javascript most likely.

Comment: Unable to replicate the described behavior.  In my example I indeed see `var username = 'domain\username';` in the page source.  Perhaps the problem is more downstream where you use `username`?

Comment: @TKoL I disagree, JS is causing the string to be parsed \character as escaped character. See below for details.

Comment: @David Indeed, but if you try running that in the JavaScript console: [Invalid Unicode escape sequence](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saGkh.png).  Depending on the username, you'll get different results.  Eg a play on my name: `var username = 'domain\thorpej'` and you get the OPs behaviour

Comment: @JamesThorpe: True.  It's also worth noting that `var username = 'domain\davidd'` produces no error.  Ultimately I think it would benefit the OP to examine what he means by "outputs".  What is the actual runtime client-side code and what is producing the output he's observing?  The behavior can be different depending on what the actual string is and what he's doing with it.  At the very least, it would be good for him to get in the habit of opening his browser tools and looking at the JavaScript code any time there's a JavaScript problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is actually stamping something like:

```
var username = 'domain\username';
```

The `\u` is being treated as an escape sequence in the JavaScript string.  Depending on what the usernames actually are, you'll see different results, from newlines, to tabs, to syntax errors.

You need to properly encode it on the server using something like [`HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd991914(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var username = '<%=HttpUtility.JavaScriptStringEncode(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name)%>';
```

Answer (score 0):

In JS (any many other languages) `\` is used in a string with a special role, called **ESCAPE CHARACTER**. You need to use `\\` to get `\` in a string, test it out in the console:

```
console.log("\");
console.log("\\");
```

It's how you form special characters like `\n` for line break etc..

I think these are all cases when you would use escape character in JS:

```
\'  single quote
\"  double quote
\\  backslash
\b  Backspace
\r  Carriage Return
\f  Form Feed
\t  Horizontal Tabulator
\v  Vertical Tabulator
```

Long story short, JS thinks `\character` is one symbol (and not \ and character after it) in the string,`\\` would represent `\`.